# xsl:sort with numbers and text

Tags: xml, xslt

I am a beginner struggling with understanding how XSL:sort works and would really appreciate your help. I got to this result from sorting an index but it is not yet quite what is needed:

```
<livre>
    <p>Aa. 1a. l) Livre d’Isaïe <?pages?>30, 106, 124.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. l0) Is 11, 12 <?pages?>30.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. l0) Is 2, 2-5 <?pages?>699.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. l0) Is 2, 3 <?pages?>696.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. la) Is 34, 1 <?pages?>36.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. la) Is 40-50 <?pages?>299.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. la) Is 42, 6 <?pages?>696.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. la) Is 44, 13-15 <?pages?>730.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. la) Is 45, 1 <?pages?>299.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. la) Is 49, 6 <?pages?>30, 658, 696.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. la) Is 56-66 <?pages?>244.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. la) Is 60, 3 <?pages?>699.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. la) Is 66, 1-2 <?pages?>284.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. la) Is 66, 20 <?pages?>699.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. la) Is 7, 14 <?pages?>246.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. m) Livre de Jérémie <?pages?>105, 106, 113, 115, 124, 301, 661.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. ma) Jr 10, 11 <?pages?>104.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. ma) Jr 13, 14 <?pages?>30.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. ma) Jr 13, 27 <?pages?>353.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. ma) Jr 25, 11-12 <?pages?>57.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. ma) Jr 25, 34 <?pages?>30.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. ma) Jr 29, 10 <?pages?>57.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. ma) Jr 29, 1-23 <?pages?>661.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. ma) Jr 29, 4-7 <?pages?>661.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. ma) Jr 7, 1-20 <?pages?>353.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. mb) Jr 29, 24-32 <?pages?>661.<?pages?></p>
</livre>
```

When I try the following on this file, nothing happens:

```
<xsl:template match="livre">
        <p><xsl:apply-templates select="./p" ><xsl:sort select="." data-type="number" order="ascending"   /></xsl:apply-templates>
</p></xsl:template>
```

My desired output would be:

```
<livre>
    <p>Aa. 1a. l) Livre d’Isaïe <?pages?>30, 106, 124.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. l0) Is 2, 2-5 <?pages?>699.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. l0) Is 2, 3 <?pages?>696.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. l0) Is 11, 12 <?pages?>30.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. la) Is 34, 1 <?pages?>36.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. la) Is 40-50 <?pages?>299.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. la) Is 42, 6 <?pages?>696.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. la) Is 44, 13-15 <?pages?>730.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. la) Is 45, 1 <?pages?>299.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. la) Is 49, 6 <?pages?>30, 658, 696.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. la) Is 56-66 <?pages?>244.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. la) Is 60, 3 <?pages?>699.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. la) Is 66, 1-2 <?pages?>284.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. la) Is 66, 20 <?pages?>699.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. la) Is 7, 14 <?pages?>246.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. m) Livre de Jérémie <?pages?>105, 106, 113, 115, 124, 301, 661.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. ma) Jr 7, 1-20 <?pages?>353.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. ma) Jr 10, 11 <?pages?>104.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. ma) Jr 13, 14 <?pages?>30.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. ma) Jr 13, 27 <?pages?>353.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. ma) Jr 25, 11-12 <?pages?>57.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. ma) Jr 25, 34 <?pages?>30.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. ma) Jr 29, 1-23 <?pages?>661.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. ma) Jr 29, 4-7 <?pages?>661.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. ma) Jr 29, 10 <?pages?>57.<?pages?></p>
    <p>Aa. 1a. mb) Jr 29, 24-32 <?pages?>661.<?pages?></p>
</livre>
```

Should I tag every data-type that needs to be sorted in a different way?
Thank you very much!

Maria

(I use XSLT version 2 with Saxon HE 9.9.1.7.)

Comment: What's the rule for the ordering? How should we know that 1a should be placed before 10?

Comment: Nothing happens, because `p` is not a number - so you are sorting by the non-value of `NaN` which is the same for all nodes being sorted. As already noted, the logic you want to apply here is not entirely clear.

Comment: Thank you very much. I just realized that what I thought was 10 was actually a lower-case L and a zero, and that is well sorted, the problem is just with the numbers after the abreviations Is and Jr.

Answer (score 0):

Saxon has an option for "alphanumeric" sorting, which seems to be what you are looking for.

See https://saxonica.com/documentation10/index.html#!extensibility/config-extend/collation